# How to call javascript function through actionLink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am not able to call javascript function through actionlink button in asp.net mvc
submitForm() is my function
My code was-:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm(state) {

           if (state != "") {
                var ele = document.frmuser.elements;
                var strvalue = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {

                    if (ele[i].type == "checkbox") {
                        if (ele[i].name == "chkactive[]") {
                            if (ele[i].checked == true) {
                                //var a = ele[i].value; alert(a);
                                if (strvalue != "")
                                    strvalue = strvalue + "," + ele[i].value;
                                else
                                    strvalue = ele[i].value;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert(strvalue);
                    if(strvalue != "" && state !="")
                    {
                        //alert(strvalue);
                        if (state == "active") {
                            location.href = '<%=Url.Action("Deletechkuser")%>' + '/' + $('select[name=chkactive[]]').val();
                        }
                        if(state == "deactive")
                        {
                            location.href = '<%: Url.Action("Deletechkuser", "Home" )%>doctors/updateStatus/' + strvalue + '/is_active/N/' + document.getElementById('hdcurpage').value + '/' + document.getElementById('hdsortkey').value + '/' + document.getElementById('hdsortdir').value;
                        }
                        if(state == "delete")
                        {
                            location.href = '<%: Url.Action("Deletechkuser", "Home" )%>' + strvalue + '/is_deleted/Y/' + document.getElementById('hdcurpage').value + '/' + document.getElementById('hdsortkey').value + '/' + document.getElementById('hdsortdir').value;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        {
                        alert('Please Select Atleast One Record');
                        document.getElementById("actions").options[0].selected=true;        
                        }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Above Code is my javascript function and now i want to pass all select value which count in strvalue get in controller i what i am do i dont know, i am not able to call function `submitForm()` on button click

My Button code was-:

```
<button class="deletebutton radius3"  id="delete" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Deletechkuser", "Home", new { id= submitForm(this.id);} )%>'">
          delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to get this line:

*i want to pass all select value which count in strvalue get in controller i what i am do i dont know*

If you were to call the `javascript` function when ActionLink is clicked you should subscribe to the `onclick` event.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text","ActionName","ControllerName",new { @onclick="MyFunction();" },null)
```

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunction(){
        //Do something
        alert('Hello world');
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps.